# OPTIONS request asks for authorisation header

Tags: java, rest, cors, authorization, camunda

Here is my web.xml file:

https://pastebin.com/SSMu7qKb

And I try to send a GET request from my application with the following headers

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'Authorization': "Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v",
'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
```

to http://localhost:8080/engine-rest/user

I traced my request using Postman. Here are the headers in the request:

```
    [{“key”:“Access-Control-Request-Method”,“value”:“GET”,“description”:""},
{“key”:“Origin”,“value”:“http://evil.com/",“description”:"”},
    {“key”:“X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client
    Id”,“value”:“6B279966ED84E2BE5D06B4F083711A81”,“description”:""},
    ,{“key”:“Access-Control-Request-Headers”,“value”:“authorization,cache-control,content-type”,“description”:""},{“key”:“Accept”,“value”:"/",“description”:""},
    {“key”:“Accept-Encoding”,“value”:“gzip, deflate, br”,“description”:""}
    ,{“key”:“Accept-Language”,“value”:“en-US,en;q=0.9”,“description”:""},
    {“key”:“Authorization”,“value”:“Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v”,“description”:""}]
```

If I add an Authorisation header in Postman to the ones I have above, I can send the request. Otherwise I get the error code 401 (Unauthorized). But OPTIONS shouldn’t ask for authorisation.

Here is the code for the filter:
https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java

The CorsFilter is the first filter in my web.xml file and in CorsFilter.java if the request is identified as **Preflight** it will not pass go to the next filter(see handlePreflightCORS method). So normally when I have an Preflight request it should not check for authorisation. So why do I get an error 401 ?